# expected number of edges for fixed min cut

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, random-graphs, graph-cut

It is known that a graph $G=(V,E)$ with $n$ nodes and min cut $k$, must have at least $\frac{1}{2}nk$ edges.

Are there any tighter bounds or expectations I can place on $|E|$ if I assume that $G$ follows a particular random graph model? Or if it is bipartite?

Comment: You might be interested in the following paper of Bollobas: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X79901390
What you say is that the edge-connectivity is at most the average degree (and then at most the minimum degree if the graph is regular), and the paper above looks at sufficient conditions for it to be an equality.

Comment: @LouisEsperet do you know if there are any special results for bipartite graphs?

Comment: Bollobas used his result (mentioned above) to prove that for almost every graph, the minimum degree and the edge-connectivity coincide (this is a simple consequence of the fact that almost every graph has diameter 2). See page 18 of http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X81902533 The same argument does not work for random bipartite graphs (they don't have diameter 2). But I'm fairly confident that the statement remains true for random bipartite graphs.